# Any way to stretch background image

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying to create a counter similar to the one [here](http://milliontrees.ca). Which counts up by stretching/squeezing images.

But I'd rather use sprites than images for the numbers. The only problem is I cannot see a way to animate a background image stretching with javascript. I know there is the background-size css3 property, but that's not available to the jquery animate method and a bit strange.

Is there any other way I could accomplish this? 
Is there a way to somehow use sprites with images instead of background-images?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap IMG tag with DIV with overflow=hidden and move it using position property. This is not very nice solution (too much elements), but it is what you need.

Comment: ay.. that's how it works on the example site, but the many image tags made it quite slow. I did it up using spans with sprites instead to try and relieve things somewhat, but it doesn't look as smooth bc the background image is just revealed rather than stretched

Comment: I am not sure if you understand me correctly. You will need exactly same amount of IMG tags as on the example site + you will need DIV wrapper for each. Using this technique, you can have all numbers (top, bottom parts) in one big image (sprites). I can make some example for you if you want.

Comment: oh maybe that is what i'm after.. you mean like absolutely positioned img inside the wrapper div?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes, that is what I am talking about :)